# Construction of $\mathbb{CP}^2$ from $S^2\times S^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces, projective-space

Show that $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is homeomorphic to the orbit space of $(S^2\times S^2)/\mathbb{Z}_2$. The action is given by $(x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$.

My attempt: I can see that $S^2\times S^2$ is a subset of $S^5$. I am unsuccessfully trying to restrict the action of $S^1$ on $S^5$ to $S^2\times S^2$ to get the required map.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3076295/mathbbcp1-times-times-mathbbcp1-s-m-mathbbcpm/3076302#3076302

Comment: I was trying to check whether the homeomorphism is a diffeomorphism or not. Can someone help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is actually a special case of a more general statement involving the [symmetric products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_product_(topology)) of $S^2$. The *$n$-fold symmetric product* $SP_n(S^2)$ is the quotient space
$$SP_n(S^2)=(S^2)^n/\Sigma_n$$
where $(S^2)^n$ denotes the $n$-fold cartesian product, and $\Sigma_n$, the group of permutations on $n$ letters, acts by permuting the factors. The claim is that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is a homeomorphism
$$SP_n(S^2)\cong \mathbb{C}P^n.$$
Your question relates to the special case of $n=2$, but it's no more trouble to establish the general result.

To begin introduce $P_n(\mathbb{C})$ as the set of non-zero complex polynomials of degree $\leq n$. The assignment
$$P_n(\mathbb{C})\ni\sum^n_{i=1}a_iz^i\mapsto (a_0,\dots,a_n)\in\mathbb{C}^n\setminus\{0\}$$
establishes a bijection between $P_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathbb{C}^n\setminus\{0\}$ which we will use to topologise $P_n(\mathbb{C})$. This yields the quotient map
$$\gamma_n:P_n(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n,\qquad \sum^n_{i=1}a_iz^i\mapsto [a_0,\dots,a_n].$$
Observe that if $f,g\in P_n(\mathbb{C})$, then $\gamma_n(f)=\gamma_n(g)$ if and only if $f$ and $g$ have the same roots (counted with multiplicity).

Now identify $S^2\cong\mathbb{C}P^1\cong\mathbb{C}\cup\infty$ as the Riemann plane and define $\varphi_n:SP_n(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow P_n(\mathbb{C})$ by
$$\varphi_n\langle\xi_1,\xi_2,\dots,\xi_n\rangle=(z-\xi_1)(z-\xi_2)\cdots(z-\xi_n),$$
with the understanding to replace $(z-\infty)$ by $1$ if it appears in the product on the right-hand side. I am not claiming that $\varphi_n$ is continuous, but rather than its composite with $\gamma_n$ is a continuous map $SP_n(S^2)\rightarrow\mathbb{C}P^n$. You should convince yourself that this is true, and that $(z-\infty)\mapsto 1$ is indeed the correct replacement to make.

Now, we remarked above that the quotient $\gamma_n$ identifies two polynomials exactly when they have identical roots, so it follows that the composite $\gamma_n\varphi_n:SP_n(S^2)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n$ is injective. On the other hand, to see that it is surjective, for $\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n\in\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ we can write
$$\prod^n_{i=1}(z-\xi_i)=\sum^n_{i=0}(-1)^i\left(\sum_{1\leq j_1<j_2<\dots< j_i\leq n}\xi_{j_1}\dots\xi_{j_i}\right) z^{n-i}$$
and so check that everything in the target indeed gets hit.

Finally we have that $\gamma_n\varphi_n$ is a continuous bijection. Since $SP_n(S^2)$ is compact and $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is Hausdorff we see that this map is a homeomorphism.

Edit: Thanks to Olivier Bégassat for a correction.

Comment: Very nice write up

Comment: I'm not seeing the rationale for replacing $z-\infty$ with $z-1$ for two reasons: you only produce polynomials of degree exactly $n$ and letting $\xi_1\to\infty$ it seems strange that this should (even after quotienting etc) correspond to adding a root at $1$. I can see a case for replacing $z-\infty$ with $-1$ for instance but I'll admit I'm not sure that's the right move either.

Comment: The idea would be somehow that the pole of order $n$ at infinity would absorb the root $\zeta_1$ (say) which we let go to infinity, thus reducing the order of the pole at $\infty$ by one and necessarily reducing the degree of the polynomial by one in parallel. It's not much of an explanation I'll admit, but something like that seems more plasible than the proposed substitution.

Comment: Oh, since we are interested in the projectivization of this the -1 doesn't matter any ways. So I would propose $$(\zeta_1,\dots,\zeta_n)\mapsto\left[\prod_{\zeta_i\neq\infty}(X-\zeta_i)\right]$$ or so.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat thanks for the suggestions. Some care needs to be taken with the last formula you suggest (the product may be empty), but it is probably a better way of doing things. I'll have a think and see if I can find an elegant way of justifying everything and make an necessary corrections.

Comment: The empty being isn't a problem: it corresponds to the line of constant polynomials.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat the emptiness isn't a problem, but the value here needs to be set by hand.